# Develop C++ Qt application GUI interfaces in HTML+javascript?

Tags: qt, user-interface, webkit

We are working on a Qt application, that we eventually want to move the the web up to some extent. For smoother transition we consider developing the user interfaces using QtWebKit in HTML/javascript. Later we want to reuse these UI pieces in the web application, when we are there.

Does it sound like a meaningful idea? How much more complicated will it be to develop the user interfaces in HTML/Javascript vs QtGui? Is it a common practice, or no?Are there any pitfalls that we should be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a common practice, but I very strongly reccomend against it. A desktop application is not a web browser. Design your logic how you want, and build your Qt interface so that it's decoupled from your log. When you want to build a web version, rebuild the UI from scratch to be a browser based client.

Comment: Any reason against this except principles?

Comment: Well, it entirely depends on the context. If you're already writing a C++ Qt ap, you should use the native GUI. It would be significantly faster. If you use HTML+javascript for the interface, you then need to roll your own interface to your back end. If you're truly building a web application, then C++/Qt is probably not the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

[The QtWebKit Bridge](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html) describes how you can combine a WebKit-based UI with business logic in C++. There also was a talk about this at the Qt DevDays; videos about the talks should appear [here](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/learning/elearning) Real Soon Now.