# Is QT the right solution for my cross-platform application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

My App is supposed to run on both Mac and PC. It needs to access the local file system and manipulate it. I also need to be able to resize images and create watermarked images as well as thumbnails. It's important for my user interfaces to look as similar as possible on both platforms.

Therefore I've been looking at QT which seems to be really up to date but I'm not very familiar with C++. I noticed that QT has support for the Webkit engine and wonder if my application UI can be written in HTML and be controlled using C++?

has anyone done this before? Any pros and cons are really appreciated.

Comment: Qt has a javascript framework that allows you to work with C++ objects at runtime (the QtScript module).  I've used it to automate some GUI testing at work.

Answer (score 7):

### Use Qt

Qt has a strong user community and easy-to-use documentation.  All of the platform-specific code is packaged up into C++ clases (QImage, QFile, etc.).

### Don't Use HTML for a Qt GUI

Caveat: If you plan on using an HTML interface I don't know if Qt is really a good solution.  The default UI for Qt is XML-based (at design-time! - at run-time it uses the native platform GUI).

I haven't personally used WebKit to implement any user interfaces with Qt and that is not the intended design.  Usually you'll invoke WebKit to display an embedded web page or help file.

### Use QML for an HTML-Like Interface in Qt

As pointed out by gvd below, if you want to design your interface using HTML-like technology, then you will want to use QML.

Sources:

- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfile.html
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtscript.html
- [Develop C++ Qt application GUI interfaces in HTML+javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340693/develop-c-qt-application-gui-interfaces-in-htmljavascript)
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeintroduction.html

Comment: Indeed, don't use QT's webkit functionality to build the UI. You can use QT's QML to style your application: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeintroduction.html

Comment: FWIW, We use webkit & html in our GUI app and it works well, except that you need to do a bit more work. Faster than ye olde widgets, and more mature than QML.

Comment: Also, QML is more for "mobile" fancy interfaces, and not so suitable for desktop/business UI.

Comment: @Macke - My concern there is that Qt might not support WebKit-based designs as well (since it is outside the norm).  Perhaps you should write an answer that shows the benefits of using WebKit for the GUI?